# jquery not working in IE after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using organictabs plugin, which I initiate in every page load in this form:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#example-one").organicTabs();

        $("#example-two").organicTabs({
            "speed": 200
        });    
    });
```

The tabs work fine in all browsers, and then I perform an ajax call which regenerates the tabs with the following code:

```
if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
{
  HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText,'page-wrap');

  $(function() {
        $("#example-two").organicTabs({
            "speed": 200                
        });                   

  });
}
```

Again, the tabs are regenerated properly and everything works fine in all browsers EXCEPT in IE, when I try to switch tabs it doesn't work. I am initiating the jquery code onreadystate change, and i really can't figure out what can the problem be with IE?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

All the best

Comment: If you open the "F12 Developer Tools", do you see any errors?

Comment: I can't see how this would cause a problem on IE, but there's no need to wrap the call in a `ready` handler, just do this: http://pastie.org/3821556 Your original code was calling `$()` and passing in a function, which is a shortcut for the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function, which is only used for initially firing your code when the page loads and the DOM is ready. You don't need (or want) to do that later. However, it *should* be harmless.

Comment: TJ Crowder, nope. The only thing I see is: HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks

Comment: silly question, is the if statement true in IE?

Comment: lnrbob i'm sorry, I don't understand the question exactly?

Comment: lnrbob sorry I just got it, yes the if statement is true

Comment: through debugging, I verified it now that the function is executing(it is displaying a normal alert within the organictabs plugin), however when clicked, the tabs don't work ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am actually getting some errors now, but only when I call the ajax page(i am getting this same error about 18 times): 

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
tenderi.php?i=4f8ec11313c01&a=4f91a1e585e90&m=0&tb=1&pg=1, line 1 character 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with how IE handles the ("a.sample_class").attr("href") attribute. In Chrome/FF the relative path is returned(in this case just the anchor #tag), whereas in IE, after I was calling an ajax page, the absolute path was being returned(http://www.mysite.com/#tag), hence trying to find the entire anchor(string) in the current page.

More information regarding this issue you can read in this article: http://www.glennjones.net/2006/02/getattribute-href-bug/

Hope this is of help to someone, as it really took a few days of my time